# Intuit Quickbooks Online app authorization quit working

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

We have a web service used to authorize a connection between our application to QuickBooks Online.  It has been working for two years with the last successful authorization on 2/28/17.  New authorization attempts can sign in with Intuit okay but when they click on the button to connect to QuickBooks, they get an error, "We're sorry! We're experiencing some problems. Please try again later."  The url displaying this error is something like, "https://appcenter.intuit.com/Connect/CompanySelection?oauth_token=qyprdVRQgReiMqcN2CZDW5U7nX2sz1iC2f4pYWbHuyY9JB".  Any ideas how I might determine what quit working?  Thank you.

Some additional information.  The authorization/deauthorization process works okay with Sandbox companies and my developer's account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, that certainly was a humbling experience and a learning one as well!  It turns out the QBO company user did not have sufficient privileges to authorize app connections.  An administrator account worked flawlessly.

Please make a note that this error message possibly means that the user is not authorized to make the connection: "We're sorry! We're experiencing some problems. Please try again later."

Answer (score 3):

One important thing to note - this error can also be caused when you try to connect to a real company with dev keys. Dev keys only work with sandbox companies. Make sure you are using your production keys to connect to a real company!

The error message really should be more descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably one of the app tokens that gets generated when you create your all through Quickbooks online, we just went through this nonsense, those token expire I believe every 3 or 6 months, something like that, contrary to almost every single other auth token that doesn't expire, and so you have to regenerate them, I almost can guarantee that is your problem.