# Why Quickbooks API is not able to open signin page for OAuth2 authentication

Tags: .net, quickbooks-online

Spent many unsuccessful hours to connect Quickbooks through API. To get started,
I downloaded sample apps from [Intuit OAuth2 Dotnet](https://github.com/IntuitDeveloper/OAuth2-Dotnet-WithoutSDK) and [OAuth2-Dotnet_UsingSDK](https://github.com/IntuitDeveloper/OAuth2-Dotnet_UsingSDK).
Followed exactly the instructions to configure web.config but both apps instead of opening QB signin page return a page with following unhelpful error message:

> We're sorry!
>   We're experiencing some problems. Please try again later.

Here is relevant part of config.web:

```
<add key="redirectURI" value="http://localhost:44334/OAuth2Manager.aspx"/>
<add key="qboBaseUrl" value="sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com"/>
<add key="discoveryURI" value="https://developer.api.intuit.com/.well-known/openid_sandbox_configuration/"/>
<add key="clientId" value="oAuth_consumer_key"/>
<add key="clientSecret" value="oAuth_consumer_secret"/>
```

[this so solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42657794/intuit-quickbooks-online-app-authorization-quit-working) didn't help either. Any suggestion what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution for this weird problem. My quickbooks developer account was created before August 17, 2017 so it was associated with OAuth1.0 whereas the sample code is for OAuth2.0. Only way to resolve this conflict is to create a new  developer account and new application after Aug 17, that will be associated with OAuth2.0 without letting you know. Intuit chose to create this mystery by not providing any indication anywhere other than the key names that in OAuth1.0 used to be consumerKey and in 2.0 is ClientKey. Unfortunately I overlooked it thinking it a typo.

**Lesson:** *Being Intuit developer requires more IQ than mine.*